# How to deploy a JAX-WS webservice which is both Service Provider and Consumer for someother Service?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I developed a Simple WebService using JDK6's in-built `JAX-WS` support and deployed on `Tomcat6` as a Web Project. 
For that I need to copy `jaxws-api.jar` into `TOMCAT_HOME/endorsed directory` (due to some class loader issues) and some `JAX-WS RI` jars into `WEB-INF/lib` and finally it is working fine.

Now I need to write a Client for some other `JAX-WS` webservice deployed somewhere else and call it from my Web App that I created.

Here I am getting errors because of having the `JAX-WS` jars in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder. 
I am able to call the webservice from a standalone java project without having `JAX-WS RI` jars on my classpath.

Can someone tell me how can I deploy a Web Project which is a WebService Provider and WebService Consumer as well?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in Metro distribution samples ant build file on what jars needs to be copied into JRE and tomcat endorsed directories. Now it is working fine.

Thank you.